# Unresolved reference: AndroidBaseExtension in gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, plugins

I am trying to create custom gradle plugin by this article
https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/gradle-kotlin-buildsrc-plugin-android/, and i stuck on this error. What i am doing wrong?

settings.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "qweqwe"
include(":app")
```

project_build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") apply false
    id("com.android.library") apply false
    kotlin("android")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class){
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

buildSrc_build.gradle.kts

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    /* Example Dependency */
    /* Depend on the android gradle plugin, since we want to access it in our plugin */
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1")

    /* Example Dependency */
    /* Depend on the kotlin plugin, since we want to access it in our plugin */
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50")

    /* Depend on the default Gradle API's since we want to build a custom plugin */
    implementation(gradleApi())
    implementation(localGroovy())
}
```

app_build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    id("com.example.myplugin")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.qweqwe"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
}
```

buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/MyPlugin.kt

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

open class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.configureAndroid()
    }
}

internal fun Project.configureAndroid() = this.extensions.getByType<AndroidBaseExtension>().run {
    compileSdkVersion(28)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(21)
        targetSdkVersion(28)
        versionCode = 2
        versionName = "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

buildSrc\src\main\resources\META-INF\gradle-plugins\com.example.myplugin.properties

```
implementation-class=MyPlugin
```

Comment: Could you post the error you are seeing?

Comment: Plugin.kt: (18, 59): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public abstract fun <T : Any!> getByType(p0: Class<TypeVariable(T)!>): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionContainer
public abstract fun <T : Any!> getByType(p0: TypeOf<TypeVariable(T)!>): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionContainer

Comment: I'm not aware of AndroidBaseExtension.  The class BaseExtension is used for configuring the base portion of the android extension.  I think that's what you want to use and why you're not finding the class AndroidBaseExtension.  The BaseExtension class is located in "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1". I see that you do correctly have a dependency on  it.

Comment: I just looked at the document that you referred to, but I was already familiar with it.  Unfortunately, the author of that document didn't say what version of the android gradle plugin was being used.  It's most likely that the name of that class has been change in later versions of the android gradle plugin.